# How can I draw in an existing tikzpicture from an lstnewenvironment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

The below example works fine if I move the `tikzpicture` environment into the after command of the `lstnewenvironment`. However, if I want to draw in an existing `tikzpicture`, the node content is not shown. It grows vertically if I add more lines of code, but they aren't visible:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
    \lstset{%
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    }%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox\bgroup\color@setgroup
}%
{%
    \color@endgroup\egroup
        \node [fill=green]
            {\box\@tempboxa};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{code}
Some Code
    \end{code}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this so that the box is shown properly but so that I can create multiple code boxes inside the same tikzpicture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the temporary box (and you were lucky `\node` didn't overwrite it before executing `\box\@tempboxa`). You can let the environment body directly fill the `\node` contents using `\node[fill=green] \bgroup` in the environment start code and `\egroup` in its end code. Because it is `\node` and not TeX's `\hbox` primitive, I think the `\color@setgroup` and `\color@endgroup` are not necessary then, although they would probably not harm. One last thing: don't forget the `\makeatother`!

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{code}{%
    \lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize}%
    \node[fill=green] \bgroup
}%
{%
    \egroup ;%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{code}
Some Code ($%@}{#\~&!)
    \end{code}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]